# Java - behavoir of an object that is equals to another object

Tags: java, object

I have a problem with Java. This is the code:

```
class Nmb {

private int value ;

public Nmb ( int value ) {
    this.value = value ;
}

public Nmb (Nmb number ) {
    value = number.value ;
}

public void duplicate ( ) {
    value = 2*value ;
}

public String  toString ( ) {
    return "" + value ;

}
public static void main ( String [ ] args ) {
    Nmb a = new Nmb ( 3 ) ;
    Nmb b = new Nmb ( a ) ;
    Nmb c = b ;
    a.duplicate ( ) ;
    b.duplicate();
    c.duplicate();
    System.out.println ( a + "," + b + ","+ c ) ;

}
}
```

The output will be: 6,12,12

I have done some tests and I have seen that b and c take the value of 12 when c.duplicate is executed. Why does this happen? Why c.duplicate calls the object b? Should't c have the value of b (3) when that object is created and work with 3 when the duplicate method is called with the result of 6,6,6? The object c will always be connected with the object b and the value of one will always depend on the value of the other?

Thank you

Comment: `b` and `c` are not two equal objects. They are the same object. That's what `c = b` does.

Comment: is not  C pointing to the same ref as B???

Comment: Think of variables as labels you can place on objects. You've labelled the same object as both `b` and `c`, so it should come as no surprise that they always show the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `c` is a reference to the same object as `b`, so these are both references that **point to the same object**.

Here you are assigning `b` to `c` (that is, you actually create a reference, not a new object):

```
Nmb c = b ;
```

So, executuing `c.duplicate()` will work for both `b` and `c`.

To make it more clear:

```
                      ______________
  b (reference)  ->  |              |
                     |  Num object  |
  c (reference)  ->  |______________|
```

Comment: Technically, `c` is not a reference to `b`. `c` is a reference to the same object as `b` is referring to. The object referenced by both has no "name", which makes it difficult to describe, so what you're saying can be considered ok, but it's technically wrong.